# unable to de-queue previous messages from a queue

Tags: java, android, rest

I am creating an chat app with android and spring using stomp over websocket. when i send more than one message to a specific client, it shows only the last message from the queue not all the previous messages. I want to see all the messages will from the queue.

**Client side**:

```
mStompClient =Stomp.over(WebSocket.class, "url");
    mStompClient.connect();


    mStompClient.topic("/topic/queue"+clientid).subscribe(topicMessage -> {


        textView.setText(topicMessage.getPayload());

    });
```

**Server side**:

```
@MessageMapping("/chat")
@SendTo("/topic/queue")

 public String sendMessage(String msg) {


    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/queue"+clientid,msg );

    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my vision, you should persist the data which sent before, then append the new incoming messages from the queue and feed data store asynchronously.

1. Step: User opens chat windows, then get data from database.
2. Step: Send message to queue and consumers should listen the queue and feed new message to chat window and data store.
3. Step: If user exit from application, No matter what happened. You can present data from data store.